# Equal sized boxes in CSS Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[Display of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiqDY.png)

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mxr6.png)

[CSS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq9gJ.png)

I want to make my display boxes all aligned, including the icons, headings and description. I am not able to do it. When I apply `justify-content: space-evenly/center;` , the horizontal alignment gets distorted.

[Distorted alignment picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsD1Z.png)

Please help!

I tried to change the `justify-content` property or `align-items` but if they are all equal sized then their heights vary due to the content and hence changes alignment horizontally. So one image is positioned at a lesser height than another, etc.

Comment: Hi Khushi, can you update your question and copy the actual code (rather than using a screen shot) to the question and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You'll have a much better chance of getting your question answered then. Good luck.

Comment: I'd have a look at [subgrid](https://youtu.be/IIQa9f0REtM?si=a2WVvV32T6qxpZEJ) 